# accumulative array in javascript for musical proposes

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create an array that increases from specific rules.

For example: 1 = 1,0,1 and 0 = 0, 0. Amount of recursion 3. 
So if I input 1 I will have:

1 -> 1 0 1

1 0 1 -> 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 -> 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1

How can I do this ?

Thanks !!

Comment: no, 1 = 1 0 1 and 0 = 0 0. So input 1 = 1 0 1 then 1 0 1 becomes 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1..and so on

Comment: Many thanks ! I'm running this in MaxMSP. Its a software for musicians. This soft implements ECMAScript 5. Probably this solutions will not run. That right ? . Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array with the given pattern an reduce the new array.

```js
var pattern = [[0, 0], [1, 0, 1]],
    depth = 3,
    temp = [1];
    
while (depth--) {
    temp = temp.reduce((t, i) => t.concat(pattern[i]), []);
}

console.log(temp.join(' '));
```

Comment: What is a "goven pattern"?

Comment: @MattMorgan sorry, typo.

Comment: :) There are a lot of design patterns...just never heard of that one lol

Answer (score 1):

At first we can create a pattern function:

```
 const pattern = (zero, one) => (values) => 
     values.reduce((res, el) => res.concat(el ? one : zero), []);
 const recurse = (f, n) => v => n == 1 ? f(v) : recurse(f, n - 1)(f(v));
```

Now to get our recursive 3 pattern we just call our simple pattern three times:

```
 const simple = recurse(pattern([0, 0], [1, 0, 1]), 3);
 const resultPattern = pattern(simple([0]), simple([1]));
```

Now you can call

```
 resultPattern([1])
```

or whatever to get your result.

Comment: I really like this functional approach

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
const rules = {
    "0": "00",
    "1": "101"
}

function expand(input, depth) {
    if (depth === 0) {
        return input;
    } else {
        var expanded = input.split('').map(function (char) {return rules[char];}).join('');
        return step(expanded, depth - 1);
    }
}

expand("1", 1) // "101"
expand("1", 2) // "10100101"
```

Comment: Many thanks ! I'm running this in MaxMSP. Its a software for musicians. This soft implements ECMAScript 5. Probably this solutions will not run. That right ? . Cheers

Comment: This is just normal javascript, so it should run :)

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to everyone! You made my day! I changed it a little bit because of how MaxMSP works.

```
autowatch = 1;

var rules = {

    "0": "00",
    "1": "101"
}

function expand(input, depth) {

    var h = input.toString();
    if (depth === 0) {
        return input;
    } else {
        var expanded = h.split('').map(function (char) {return rules[char];}).join('');
        return expand(expanded, depth - 1);
    }
}

function test(x,y){

    post(expand(x,y))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function.

```js
let convert = (recursion, current) => {
  if (recursion === 0) return current;  
  return convert(--recursion, build(current));
};

let build = (str) => {
  return str ? (str.split(' ').map((s) => s === '1' ? ' 1 0 1' : ' 0 0').join('').trim()) : '1 0 1';
};

console.log(`1 => ${convert(1)}`);
console.log(`2 => ${convert(2)}`);
console.log(`3 => ${convert(3)}`);
console.log(`4 => ${convert(4)}`);
console.log(`5 => ${convert(5)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I think the OP wants something that will take a recursion param as an argument.  EG, feed the result back in to the function 3x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that takes care of repeating the operation *n* times. I'll call it `expand`, and it takes an array of 0's and 1's as first argument `input`, and a number for the amount of `repeats` as second argument.

*for `expand([1], 3)` the expected output would be `[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]`*

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} input 
 * @param {number} repeats 
 */
function expand(input, repeats) {

    do input = input.reduce((arr, oneOrZero) => arr
      .concat([[0, 0], [1, 0, 1]][oneOrZero]), []);
    
    while(--repeats > 0);

    return input;
}


log([1], 1); // expected output: 1,0,1

// one expansion is always performed:
log([1], Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY); // expected output: 1,0,1

log([1, 0], 2); // expected output: 1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0
log([1], 3); // expected output: 1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1

function log(input, repeats) {
    document.body.innerHTML += `<p>${input} => x${repeats} => ${expand(input, repeats)}</p>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet loves these small challanges. Here is my minimalistic stab at it.

```
let generate = (in, rule) =>  in.reduce((p,c) => [...p, ...rule(c)], []);
let tune = generate([1,0,1], (in) => in ? [1,0,1] : [0,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

@Francisco Colasanto, seeing your answer, may I suggest something simplest (and fastest) using string.replace() and regex :

```js
function expand(input, depth) {
    var h = input.toString();
    for (var i=0;i<depth;i++) {
    var str = h.replace(/0/g,"0,0").replace(/1/g,"1,0,1");
      h=str;
    }
    return h.replace(/,/g,"");
}

console.log(expand(1,3));
console.log(expand([1,0,1],2));
console.log(expand([101],2));
```